# 'CTRL-ALT-T' not working in Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: lubuntu, lxterminal

I'm new to Linux, ubuntu, and lubuntu so this might be an easy fix.

Today I installed Lubuntu 18.04 and suddenly after a reboot the lxterminal won't launch via 'CTRL-ALT-T' anymore. It still works perfectly fine after launching through run or the menu. The shortcut simply doesn't work anymore.

I think it broke because I was messing around in 'default applications for lxsession'. I changed around some default programs, such as VLC. I don't think I changed the 'Terminal manager' launch application but even if I did, I'm pretty sure I've reset it to what it was before (lxterminal &) and it still isn't working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.[image]

Comment: Ctrl-alt-t is not a magic combo. Something has to bind it to an app. Look in `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml`.

Comment: [IMG]http://i66.tinypic.com/2i0u33p.png[/IMG] I don see what is wrong with this. Edit: wrong image

Comment: I changed the shortcut from [IMG]http://i66.tinypic.com/2i0u33p.png[/IMG] to simply "lxterminal" and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To map keyboard shortcuts in Lubuntu / LXDE you can edit
`~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml`
and restart openbox via
`$ sudo openbox --reconfigure`
to reload the configuration.

Or you can use `lxhotkey`, a simple program to set up keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: I changed the shortcut from [IMG]http://i66.tinypic.com/2i0u33p.png[/IMG] to simply "lxterminal" and now it works. Thanks!